# Time array in javascript Ember JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, time, ember.js

I want to create a array of system time with following format

```
["4:01pm","4:06pm","4:11pm","4:16pm","4:21pm","4:26pm"]
```

assuming the system current time is `4:26pm`

How can I create this in javascript by getting current system time

Comment: So is what you are looking for the current system time plus the time at previous 5 minute intervals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var i = 6, result = [], time = new Date();
while (i--) {
  var hours = time.getHours(), minutes = time.getMinutes();
  result[i] = ((hours - 1) % 12 + 1) + ':' +
      (minutes < 10 ? '0' : '') +
      minutes + (hours < 12 ? 'am' : 'pm');
  time = new Date(time - 5 * 60 * 1000);
}
console.log(result);
// ["8:59am", "9:04am", "9:09am", "9:14am", "9:19am", "9:24am"]
```